# Show basis for infinite dimension space

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $\ell^2(J) = \{ x = (x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in J} \mid x_\alpha \in
> \mathbb{C},\, \sum_{\alpha \in J} |x_\alpha|^2 < \infty\}$, and let $B =
> \{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in J}$, where $e_\alpha = (e_{\alpha}^j)_{j\in J}$ is given by
>
> $$e_\alpha^j = \begin{cases}e_\alpha^j =0, \text{ if } \alpha \ne j,\\ e_\alpha^j = 1, \text{ if } \alpha = j, \end{cases}$$
>
> Show that $B$ is a Hilbertian basis for $\ell^2(J)$.

So we need to show that $\overline{\text{span}(B)} = \ell^2(J)$, but I've got no idea of how $\overline{\text{span}(B)}$ would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Hilbert space $H$  a set $B$ spans a dense subspace if and only if the only vector orthogonal to every vector on $B$ is the zero vector. Suppose $v$ is orthogonal to $e_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha \in J$. Then $ \langle v,e_{\alpha}  \rangle =v_{\alpha}$ . Since this is $0$ for all $\alpha$ we get $v=0$.